# form onchange AJAX function for PHP database query

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms

I am quite new to AJAX and would appreciate any help. I have been trying to use AJAX onchange of first drop down menu to call a function for PHP to query database and populate matching results to second drop down menu.
My db connect script works fine, and my PHP query accurately pulls the correct info from the database. (when not using posted variable $cityinput) Problem has been with getting the result from PHP to AJAX, and displayed in the second drop down menu.

```
<?php
require'connect.php';

$cityinput=$_POST['cityinput'];

$query="SELECT mname FROM masseurs WHERE lounge='$cityinput'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_numrows($result);

echo "<b><center>Database Output</center></b><br><br>";
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {
$mname=mysql_result($result,$i,"mname");

$mname="<option value=''>"mname"</option>";
$i++;}

if (!mysql_query($query))
  {die('Error: ' . mysql_error());}
mysql_close();
?> 





<html>
<head>
<script>
function getmasseurs()
{if (str=="")
  {document.getElementById("masseurinput").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("masseurinput").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","outputpopulate3.php?$mname="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>


</head>
<body>
<form id="book" action="test.php" method="post">
  <p align="center"> 
    <select name="cityinput" id="cityinput" onchange="getmasseurs()">
      <option value="0" selected>City</option>
      <option value="1">Brisbane</option>
      <option value="2">Sydney</option>
      <option value="3">Melbourne</option>
      <option value="4">Adelaide</option>
      <option value="5">Perth</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p align="center"> 
    <select name="masseurinput" size="1" id="masseurinput"><div id="cityinput"></div> 
    </select>
  </p>
  <p align="center"> 
    <input type="submit">
</form></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just realised I had a piece of code missing for populating the second drop down menu. But it didnt work anyway:<div id="cityinput"></div>

Comment: $mname="<option value=''>"mname"</option>"; should be $mname="<option value=''>$mname</option>";

Answer (score 0):

This appears wrong: `xmlhttp.open("GET","outputpopulate3.php?$mname="+str,true);` 
Which file is outputpopulate3.php? The top one? If not post the code of that file

Why are you using a variable in it ? $mname. You can't just use PHP code inside of javascript.

If you want to that you should use:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","outputpopulate3.php?<? echo $mname; ?>="+str,true);
```

Also, the 'str' variable in this line is never set..
You can set it like this in a previous line:

```
str = document.getElementById('masseurinput').value;
```

But probably it would be easier to just use a fixed variable name..